# How to make three div with 2nth div is Add and Remove button in CSS

Tags: html, css, mobile

I want to make it like below image:
[image]

Comment: pls post snippets of your codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="flex">
    <div class="left">List A</div>
    <div class="center">
      <div class="left-arrow"><<</div>
      <div class="right-arrow">>></div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">List B</div>
</div>
```

css

```
.flex{
  display: flex;
}
.left{
  width: 40%;
  height: 300px;
}
.right{
  width: 40%;
  height: 300px;
}
.center{
  width: 10%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 300px;
}
.center .left-arrow{
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 375px){
  .flex{
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .left,.right,.center{
    width: 100%;
  }
  .center{
    padding: 15px 0;
  }
  .center .left-arrow{
    margin: 0;
    margin-right: 15px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use another html files to show on mobiles.:P

Comment: Same here dude, Gives me more control.